# Get data attributes from v-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Sure it's a easy thing but at the moment i just can't get it to work. I have a component called *posts.vue* which includes this link in the template:

```
<template>
    <a v-link="{ name: 'post', params: { slug: post.post_name }}" v-postid="{ post.ID }"><h2>{{ post.post_title }}</h2></a>
</template>
```

My Routes are set up like this:

```
'/post/:slug': {
    name: 'post',
    component: require('./components/post.vue')
}
```

Now my question is how can i get the *postid* data attribut in my post.vue component which gets loaded after the route matches.

In my old jquery days i would do it like that:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    var attr = $(this).data('post-id');
}
```

(Just to showcase what i meant)

Thanks for any help guys! Vue.js is great so far, enjoy it alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a post object inside your component that you set with ajax after the route is loaded

```
data: function() {
  return {
    post: {}
  }
}
```

and

```
route: function() {
  data: function() {
    var resource = fetchPost(this.$route.params.slug)
    this.$set('post', resource)
  }
}
```

You can access the post.id everywhere in your component like this `this.$data.post.id`
The v-postid directive is not required for that.